# Image problem in iphone

Tags: iphone, image, uiimageview

I am passing images from array to a UIImageView. These images changes according to situation....But i have found that some images never appear when the corresponding condition is satisfied...and the problem is with those images..

When i changed them with other one then other are working

Is there any special format of image that UIImageView support

Comment: @Jacob Relkin --My code is correct because when i replace that imagename with other one it shows....

Comment: may i know you store image name or uiimage in array or have web url of image in array

Comment: @GhostRider-- NSArray *array=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"My-hair-care.jpg",@"Boxer.png",@"weeping.jpg",@"great.png"];

Comment: @GhostRider--only first image is visible

Comment: your two images are of png formate and other two are jpg formate how you showing image in imageview

Comment: use ur image in this way NSString *imageSTring = [array objectatindex:i];[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageSTring]];

Comment: imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[array objectAtIndex:i]]; ......where i is variable

Comment: according to me its have to work check images in you bundle if they have same name that you written in array

Comment: is you check your image name is correct or not

Comment: YES names are correct...I also tried same method in another Testproject and it works perfect there.......

Comment: @GhostRider--I need help....please come on skype..my skype name is ranjeet.cssoft

Answer (score 1):

We need to see a code sample, otherwise we’re just making things up. You mentioned the following code in the comments:

```
NSArray *array= [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
    @"My-haircare.jpg", @"Boxer.png", @"weeping.jpg", @"great.png"];
```

This is wrong, you need to terminate the object list with `nil`:

```
NSArray *array= [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
    @"My-haircare.jpg", @"Boxer.png", @"weeping.jpg", @"great.png", nil];
```

This could very well be the source of your problem. But as I said, without code we’re just guessing.

Comment: @zoul---my mistake because i was just written dummy code here but in actual i wrote nil at the end.....i have replaced all my images with other one and it is working...But well picked thanks...